# Error in Saas when trying to deploy in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, heroku

I get the following error when I try to deploy my application in Heroku.

```
Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker
```

I'm using this datapicker of react :
https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker

I added this line in my my application.rb

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')
```

Also in the application.scss

```
@import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker";
```

It runs fine locally but it does not deploy.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Is your `/node_modules` dir checked into GIT? Otherwise you need to use a buildpack on heroku that installs the modules via NPM https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

Comment: @max I'm already using the buildpacks for ruby and node